# Overflow Error 6 Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, integer-overflow

I'm using a counter to keep track of true/false conditions in a range, with the value of that counter used to determine further action.  However, I'm getting an overflow error even when a small (15 row) data set is being read.  Here's the code:

```
Dim b As Double     'Exceptions Sheet
Dim u As Integer    'Unhandled exception counter

b = 2

Sheets("Exceptions").Activate

Do While Sheets("Exceptions").Cells(b, 2).Value <> ""
    If Sheets("Exceptions").Cells(b, 14).Value <> "A" Then
        u = u + 1
    End If
Loop
    b = b + 1
```

~Thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not changing the value of `b` in the loop, so it just keeps incrementing `u` until it overflows